# Opa : passing database as function parameters

Tags: database, function, arguments, opa

I'd like to pass a database to an opa function. I've tried the following code, but it doesn't work :

```
database int /db1;
database int /db2;


function add(db, int i)
{
        db = i
}


add(db1, 12)
add(db2, 42)
```

You can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a ref path (`@/db`) and `Db.*` functions ( http://doc.opalang.org/module/stdlib.core.db/Db )

```
database int /db1;
database int /db2;

function add(db, int i)
{
    Db.write(db, i)
}

add(@/db1, 12)
add(@/db2, 42)
```